# My Account has lost some of its associations

Tags: support, stack-overflow, area-51

Problem: My account has lost its attachment to Gravatar on SO, lost rep and a badge on SO, lost rep and activity on Area 51, lost privileges in chat rooms I belong to in SO Chat.

What occurred: I was logged in to SO, and SO Chat as Pyrodante, a member of the chat linked an article on Area 51, so I went there to give an answer. When I finished my answer it said I could not post anonymously even though I was logged in, so I logged out and logged back in via my Google authentication (like I always use), and suddenly the accounts were broken.

It actually appears like my account may have been re-created, all of my badges are listed as awarded at the moment I logged in to the broken account.

The badge I lost was from starred comments in SO chat, as if my SO profile and my SO Chat profile are not speaking to one another.

[Here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/747732/pyrodante) is my correct profile that seems to now be missing

Comment: Your questions/answers count has also changed, you've only asked one question on SO, according to http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/167336/pyrodante?tab=accounts. Weird.

Comment: I believe this is the same issue as http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118198/a-message-says-you-have-no-other-accounts-on-the-stack-exchange-network-but-i, which is now fixed.

Comment: While the problems seem related, my situation has not changed.

Comment: Correction: It appears that my SO account is somewhat back, my questions and answers are now showing correctly, but my image, and my chat identity are still messed up

Comment: What I find interesting is the change image button sends me to the gravatar page, with me logged in, and my old picture selected, its just not displaying in any of my SE areas.

Answer (score 7):

If I'm reading this right, it looks like the profile that you linked to as correct (id 747732) was merged with an older account (id 706836) via the account recovery process.

I see the tag vote counts seem to be off, and I'm not sure what happened to your badges either -- normally a merge puts all of that together. Do the question/answer counts look right to you? I'm seeing 110 answers and 10 questions right now.

You can try updating the parent user on your chat profile to the [account that resulted from the merge](https://stackoverflow.com/users/706836/pyrodante).

Beyond that... moderators don't have access to deleted user accounts (which is what happened to the one you linked to when it got merged), so we might have to get a developer to take a look at what happened exactly and whether everything is as it should be.

Comment: I have the same problem as the OP... I had 31 account associations yesterday.  Today I have Area 51.  Something smells funny.

Comment: I didn't merge anything, I had an account on SO and an attached account on Area 51, my SO Account is now borked and my Area 51 seems to be completely new. (I had 51 rep now I have 1)

Comment: @Pyrodante I passed your meta post up the chain and I'm told that devs are looking into it. Unfortunately I can't do anything else as a moderator.

Comment: Hey I sure do appreciate it!

Comment: @Pyrodante No problem. I hope it's worked out soon. :)

Comment: I have my associated accounts back now.  All show up now.  Thanks for any assistance provided. +1

Comment: As a follow up: I have managed to recover or make up for most of my losses, and most of my accounts seem to be fine, however there is still the oddity that my chat uses the default gravatar instead of using the one from my account like it is supposed to.

Comment: Not sure if it fixed itself or not, but now it is working thanks!