# My chat profile is not synchronized again, can anyone fix this?

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, chat

So, trying to visit [my favorite bar](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118/root-access) as usual I suddenly again have no permission to talk anymore:

[image]

How does one have `20` reputation on `The Stack Exchange Network`?

Going to [my chat profile](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/250/tom-wijsman), I see that I am connected through the account `Super User Tom Wijsman`.

[image]

Changing the parent user around doesn't make a difference.

[image]

I feel that looks rather odd, and more interesting is that it picks my reputation up as `0`.

However, I have [19+k reputation on Super User](https://superuser.com/users/9666/tom-wijsman).

[image]

What happened? *I feel desynchronized again...*

Comment: I wonder if [something larger is going on here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118178/my-account-has-lost-some-of-its-associations)...problormz!

Comment: Pretty nice bug. 0 rep :)

Comment: @jadarnel27: As far as I understand this is when a inconsistent synchronization happens, but it should be unrelated to account merge problems like experienced in that question.

Comment: I synchronized your account (changing the parent user doesn't do that). Not sure yet what happened; will look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is fixed, it was a timeframe of about 2 minutes during which a profile refresh contained no accounts. I'll leave the explanation to Kevin, who I'm assuming is going to post a post-mortem on the related [A message says "You have no other accounts on the Stack Exchange network", but I do](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118198/a-message-says-you-have-no-other-accounts-on-the-stack-exchange-network-but-i) (or one of its gazillion dupes). As far as chat is concerned, this was restricted to those 2 minutes though.

Answer (score 3):

By "The Stack Exchange Network" it means you just need 20 rep network-wide, not on one particular site. I manually synced your chat profile and it says you have 44.7k rep now, so you should be able to get back into chat. I don't know what would've caused it to drop to 0 though; you'll probably need to wait for a dev to look into it

---

**Edit**: The whole network is [having](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118198/a-message-says-you-have-no-other-accounts-on-the-stack-exchange-network-but-i) [problems](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118201/stackexchange-errors-xxx-temporarily-unavailable), so it's probably part of that; your last sync couldn't find any accounts, so your total rep became 0