# Network Profile information reporting 'temporarily unavailable'

Tags: support, profile-page, network-profile

Stack Exchange network user profiles like
[this one](https://stackexchange.com/users/102159/grace-note),
[this one](https://stackexchange.com/users/248988), and
[this one](https://stackexchange.com/users/127979/kevin-vermeer)
are reporting *XXX temporarily unavailable* where XXX is

- Top questions/answers
- Filtered questions
- Accounts
- Reputation
- Activity
- Favorites
- Filters

Interestingly, newsletter subscriptions and flair (with correct reputation and account information) seem to be intact.

Comment: Probably the same thing causing http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118198/a-message-says-you-have-no-other-accounts-on-the-stack-exchange-network-but-i

Comment: @Michael - Yeah, probably.  Didn't see that before I began my edit.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, it is temporarily unavailable, like the error says - I don't mean to be snarky, but that's *why the message is there*.

Comment: Lack of snarky intent noted. Still chuckle-worthy, though, as a general thing :)

Comment: I had no trouble interpreting the message. Are you hinting that it's inappropriate to report the site partially down? To put it another way, are all StackExchange outages planned and well known to the site admins? ;-)

Comment: @MetaEd - When we display a message *specifically* stating that, yes, it's a known outage :)

Comment: I didn't want to assume. It seemed equally possible that, when some database is unreachable, the error message indicating the fact is nice and friendly rather than cryptic. Thanks for the update.